# Can a link to the question page help be added to the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

I am missing a link to a help page on the questions page on the symbolism used here.

This help page should answer questions like:

- What does a yellow background mean?
- What does a green answer number background mean?
- What does a yellow answer number foreground color mean?

These questions are asked many times in "meta".

Comment: If implemented this should probably not include color names, but the actual example of the style, as it could/would be different on every stack exchange site.

Comment: @RickSladkey - How is this a possible duplicate? This is a request to add the information to the on-site FAQs.

Comment: @RickSladkey Read the last phrase in the question. The OP is adressing the absence of backgrounds' documentation at the faq.

Answer (score 1):

The site FAQ is a highly-condensed README file.  It's sole purpose is to get people familiar with the basics, so that they don't run afoul of the community guidelines.  It is as short as possible, and as simple as possible, so that *people will read it.*

When you propose an addition to the site FAQ, you have to ask yourself this question:  Will this new information *help the new user*

1. Find out what the site is about?
2. Avoid closed questions and deleted answers?
3. Be a productive new member of the community?

If the value of the new information doesn't contribute to these objectives, in a manner that substantially outweighs the complexity of adding it to the FAQ, then it doesn't belong in the FAQ.

There are many things that could be added to the FAQ that are not there, for good reason.  Have a look at the [Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites); all of this information is on Meta, and not in the main FAQ, because it is information that is important, but not important enough for the new user to know immediately.

In short, I don't believe information having to do with the color backgrounds of posts is important enough to be included in the site FAQ, because it is not information that is *essential* to the new user.

There is a Meta FAQ specifically devoted to what the colors mean; it is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean  If someone asks you about the colors, just refer them there.

Comment: In my original question, which has been edited by others since, I asked for a link to a help page, not for an addition to the FAQ. In my opinion, I should be able to get answers to these simple but fundamental questions without having to go to another site, search for several different questions on this topic and then get the info from answer #17 of question X, answer #1 of question Y and answer #4 of question Z. Books often explain the conventions used at the beginning of the book. I would like to have this kind of information concentrated on an official, easily accessible page.

Comment: Fair enough.  The link is at the top of this page.